# How to create rails api project with rails 4.2.7 and ruby 2.3.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-api

I want to create a rails api project from command line with rails 4.2.7 and ruby 2.3.3. I tried with this command `rails _4.2.7_ new app_name --api` but this command takes rails 5.

Comment: you should use ruby version from 1.9.3 to 2.2.x for rails 4.x if we are used ruby 2.3.3 then it recommended for rails 5.

Answer (score 3):

you should use ruby version from 1.9.3 to 2.2 for rails 4.x if we are used ruby 2.3.3 then it recommended for rails 5

**Ruby Versions**

> You should use the newest version of Ruby with a new Rails
>   application. Rails versions 3.2 to 4.2 were built to work with any
>   version of Ruby from 1.9.3 to 2.2, allowing flexibility. However,
>   Rails 5.0 requires Ruby 2.2.2 or newer. If you have an older
>   application, take time to make sure it runs on the newest version of
>   Ruby so you can upgrade to Rails 5.0.

Please see below links for more details -

http://railsapps.github.io/updating-rails.html

http://www.devalot.com/articles/2012/03/ror-compatibility

Comment: If I moved to ruby 2.2.4 then how can I do this?

Comment: Hope these links will help you.

Answer (score 1):

This version number (4.2.7) fits semantic versioning 2.0.0!

See below link -

https://www.versioneye.com/ruby/rails/4.2.7

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#ruby-versions

This is probably the best source as it is controlled by the Rails core team.

```
Ruby Versions Rails generally stays close to the latest released Ruby version when it's released:

    Rails 5 requires Ruby 2.2.2 or newer.
    Rails 4 prefers Ruby 2.0 and requires 1.9.3 or newer.
    Rails 3.2.x is the last branch to support Ruby 1.8.7.
    Rails 3 and above require Ruby 1.8.7 or higher.
    Support for all of the previous Ruby versions has been dropped officially. You should upgrade as early as possible.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using gemset as well. Hope this might help you

```
rvm gemset create rails4.2.7
rvm use ruby-2.3.1@rails4.2.7
gem install rails -v 4.2.7
```

Then create your rails app

```
rails new app_name --api
```